# How to update all but one python packages?

Tags: python, pip, python-3.8

I've multiple python packages installed on my system. My update script calls `pip-review --local --auto` to update all the python packages. However, I don't want to update all packages. What I want is `pip-review` to update all packages except `scons`, since one of my programs needs an older version of `scons`. Currently to do this, I run `pip-review --local --auto && python3 pip uninstall -y scons && python3 -m pip install -Iv scons==3.1.2` which updates all packages and then uninstalls the new version of `scons` and then re-installs it with a specific version number. Is there a nicer way to do this?

Comment: This is exactly why you should use a virtual environment for each project

Comment: IMO there is no simple way. Either use `pip-review --local --interactive` or `pip-review --local --auto && python3 -m pip install -U scons==3.1.2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments and answers posted by other users, I've decided to go for the following piece of command to update all packages except scons:
`pip-review --local --auto && python3 -m pip install -U scons==3.1.2`

Thanks a lot to everyone for helping me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install -r $(grep -v '^ *#\|^pkg1\|^pkg2' requirements.txt | grep .)
```

This is a shell hack to exclude pkg1, pkg2, etc. from a pip install using requirements.txt, but you may want to modify it and see if it suits your purpose. But like the other guy said, use a virtualenv going forward.

Comment: The OP asks about `pip-review`, not `requirements.txt`.

Comment: I was under the impression pip-review could also use bash and piping to make the same code viable. My bad.